# Basis change qestion

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. Suppose we have two bases of $V$, $B=(e_1,...,e_n)$ and $B'(f_1,...,f_n)$. We can express $f_j$ in terms of the basis $B$:

$$f_j=p_{1j}e_1+p_{2j}e_2+...+p_{nj}e_n,\quad 1\le j \le n,p_{ij}\in K.$$

We define a matrix $P \in M_n(K)$ by $P=(p_{ij})$. So, column $j$ is the column vector $(f_j)_B$. We call $P$ a change of basis matrix from $B'$ to $B$.

So, here are a few questions: Why isn't $P$ a change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$? If we look at the construction of $f_j$, we clearly see that $P$ goes from $B$ to $B'$. Is it wrong?

If it is wrong, I found the following proposition:

> Let $V, B, B'$ and $P$ be as defined above, and let $v \in V$. Then  $P\cdot(v)_{B'}=(v)_{B}$

I don't really see why this statement holds, as I see $P$ as a change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$ and not conversely.

If someone could give a clear explanation to all of this, I would really appreciate it. I tried to look for some articles on the internet, but I didn't really understand. Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is indeed a basis change from $B'$ to $B$.

If you have some vector $v \in V$ written as $v = \sum_i v_i e_i = \sum_i v_i' f_i$, then notice that
\begin{align}
v &= \sum_{j=1}^n  v_j' f_j\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n  v_j\: \underbrace{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} e_i \right)}_{(f_j)_B}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \underbrace{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} v_j'\right)}_{=v_i}\: e_i
\end{align}
Thus, we see that multiplying the components from the $B'$ basis, $v_j'$, by $P$ gives us the components in the unprimed basis $B$, ($v_j$).

There is something slightly tricky here, in that if you write $v$ as a column vector in the $B'$ basis
\begin{align}
v &= \begin{bmatrix}v_1' \\ v_2' \\ \vdots \\ v_n'\end{bmatrix}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
and you set
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{bmatrix} &= P\begin{bmatrix}v_1' \\ v_2' \\ \vdots \\ v_n'\end{bmatrix}
\tag{2}
\end{align}
then you need to be aware of the fact that the LHS of Eqn. $(2)$ is in the $B$ basis, while the RHS of Eqn. $(1)$ is in the $B'$ basis.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the idea. If someone could correct and complete it, it would be cool!

So, in reality, $P$ is a matrix of basis change from $B$ to $B'$. But, we can probably see the $P$ as an identity application which goes from $B'$to $B$, i.e. $(id)_{B'}^{B}$. The explanation to this is because if we express $f_j$ in terms of $B$, we get it's composantes in $B$, but multiplication $P$ and $(v)_{B'}$ together we get something in $B$. It is not really clear and rigorous, but I think it holds!

Comment: In my experience, it is indeed best to see $P$ as the matrix of the identity with respect to the bases $B$, $B'$. In general if $T$ is a linear map between vector spaces $V$,$W$, and $[T]_{B,B'}$ is the matrix with respect to bases $B,B'$, then you indeed have that $[T]_{B,B'} \cdot [v]_B = [Tv]_{B'}$.

Comment: @AlejandroEpelde Yes I'm agree, if you consider applications with respect to basis it is more logic and makes much more sens :D